# How does TCP multiplexing different from UDP multiplexing?

Tags: tcp, udp, multiplexing

How is TCP multiplexing different from UDP multiplexing?

I know that TCP uses 4 identifiers for multiplexing-depmultiplexing(source IP, source port number, destination IP, destination port number) whereas UDP uses 2 identifiers( destination IP, destination port number).

This is all I currently know about the issue.

If you could let me know more about the similarities and differences, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong. UDP packets carry source and destination addresses and ports just like TCP packets do.